# Significant audio lag in davinci resolve when using pipewire

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pipewire, davinci-resolve

I'm using pipewire on an Ubuntu system, and [it's been reported](https://www.reddit.com/r/davinciresolve/comments/phizng/significant_audio_latency_on_linux/) that this is the cause of serious audio lag in Davinci Resolve.

The advice given is to "instal pulseaudio-alsa" but I don't want to use pulseaudio over pipewire.

How can I fix this massive (~1s) audio lag while still using pipewire?

Answer (score 0):

In your link a guy mentions that he is on Arch Linux, and that he had a file called .asoundrc in his home directory.

He overwrote it's content with the following:

```
pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse
```

I am on Ubuntu 22.10 and I didn't have such a file, so I created it ... and it works! No lag in Resolve now!

Steps:

```
# touch /home/<user/.asoundrc
# gedit /home/<user>/asoundrc
```

paste in the following:

```
pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse
```

and save it.

Restart pipewire:

```
# systemctl --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse
# systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

Voila - no more lag in resolve (at least on my system)